# Core Data, sort with other language

Tags: core-data

In my app, `NSSortDescriptor` for English works fine now. But it doesn't work for other languages. I tried to type in Chinese, the order of fetched result is unsorted. What should I do to sort other languages like Chinese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends by what you want to sort it. Number of strokes? Pinyin? Some other criteria? I suggest you add an attribute to your entity that reflects the logic and use that in your sort descriptor.

Also, try to create your sort descriptor with a selector, specifically

```
@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)
```

Comment: I want to sort Chinese characters not Pinyin. `@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)` works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Note: you need to set system language to the language you want to sort. e.g.For sorting Chinese characters, set system language to Chinese.